# How can I avoid parameter sharing between python instances

Tags: python, class

Consider this example (which is similar to my problem):

```
    class Item():
       test = []
       parent = None
       _is_item = True
       def __init__(self):
            subitems_list = []
            for name in dir(self):
                if not name.startswith('_'):
                    item = getattr(self, name)
                    if hasattr(item, '_is_item'):
                        subitems_list.append((name, item))
            self._subitems = dict(subitems_list)
            for name, item in self._subitems.items():
                item.parent = self
       def __call__(self):
          if self.parent is not None:
             print(self.parent.test)
    
       def __iter__(self):
       for key, item in self._subitems.items():
            yield item

class myItem(Item):
    test = [3]
    sub = Item()
    pass


class A(Item):
  b = myItem()



class C(Item):
  b = myItem()

a = A()
c = C()
a.b.sub()
c.b.sub()

a.b.test = [2]
print("-------------- then:")

a.b.sub()
c.b.sub()
```

The result is:

```
[3]
[3]
-------------- then:
[3]
[3]
```

I tried to use `myItem` in two classes (because they both have this item). However, it seems this definition changes the `parent` of subitems for each instance. For this reason when I change the value of `test` for `myItem` instance in one class, it doesn't affect the results.

How can I avoid this problem, and what is your suggestions for this senario?

Comment: Declare instance variables rather than class variables: initialize `test` inside `__init__` (`self.test = []`) rather than in the `class` block. See e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3.

Comment: I guess I did that, and it didn't work, the problem is that the `parent` changes for subitems and subitems are class properties. Maybe I shouldn't use parent for them.